# Why my Google Chrome extensions stopped working?

Tags: 13.04, google-chrome, chromium, webapps

I just installed Ubunt 13.04 on my PC and everything seems to be working great. The only thing is that Google Chrome's (not Chromiun) extensions just stopped working. All the icons were replaced by a puzzle piece and they don't responde. Also if I click "update extensions now" nothing happens

[image: Here is a screenshot]

Is there any way to fix them?

Comment: "I just installed Ubunt 13.04 on my PC and everything seems to be working great. The only thing is that Google Chrome's (not Chromiun) extensions just stopped working." is not clear to me. Are you saying that Google Chrome's extensions worked previously, before you installed 13.04? What did you have before? Is this a clean install or an upgrade? Do you have a separate home folder? Your AdBlock Plus is the latest version. Have you tried as a new Google Chrome user (menu, settings, add new user)?

Comment: I upgraded from 12.04 tu 13.04 and they all worked. Then I formatted my PC and installed 13.04 from scratch, then the extensions stopped working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the solution was to delete and re-install all extension. They all work fine now.